# Dynamo DB ORM mapping with Spring Data DynamoDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to map my Dynamo DB JSON to Java ORM mapping in Spring Data jpa using annotations. My JSON would be like

```
{
  "name": "b",
  "in": {
    "val": {
      "sum": {
        "negatives": [
          "1*",
          "2*"
        ],
        "positives": [
          "1#",
          "2#",
          "3#",
          "4#"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my class mapping is,

```
  @Entity
    @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "test")
    public class Test {

    @Id
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String name;

    private In in;

    
    @DynamoDBDocument
    public class In {
        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "val")
        private Val val;
    }

    @DynamoDBDocument
    public class Val {
        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "sum")
        private Sum sum;
    }

    
    @DynamoDBDocument
    public class Sum {
        private List<String> negatives;
        private List<String> positives;

    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="in")
    public In getIn() {
        return insights;
    } 
    public void setIn(In in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

}`
```

Below error,

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.datahandler.dto.test$In, at table: test, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(in)]

Comment: This is not going to work so easily. With relational data you have mappings (one to one, one to many, many to one) between objects. You cannot just throw an `@Entity` on your class and call it a day. You will probably have to restructure your data in order to make sense in a relational environment.

Comment: The data in DB is stored by a third party app, and we need to read from DB, so i dont have options to restructure the data in DB. Any way to do the ORM mapping?

Comment: I would suggest that you don't use ORM and do the manual mapping directly from the AttributeValue Map. I spent a while trying to get ORM to work with DynamoDb and I felt the documentation for edge-cases/integration with other systems was lacking, and it just ended up not being worth the time.

Comment: can you share an example? Jensen Lo